# JQuery UI disabling reorder in sortable lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, interface

So I have two sortable lists in a web app I'm writing. What I want to do is make one of the lists not be reorder-able, but allow it's items to be dragged onto the other list. Items from list one can be dropped on list two, but items on list one can't be rearranged.

Another thing I want to do is to make it so when items are dragged off of list one they're not removed from list one; the dragged item is only dragging a copy.

The end goal is to have a toolbox thing that allows the user to drag elements into a "canvas" of sorts. Elements in the toolbox aren't rearrangement and once they're dragged off the don't go away (so the user is just dragging copies).

Help with either disabling reordering or making copies dragged off would be much appreciated!

(I can post my list code if you guys need it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neve mind! I found the answer after browsing the docs more. The solution is to use plain draggable+sortable elements:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

Comment: could you elaborate pls or post an example?